# Insert list <string> into database using Java

Tags: java

I want to insert list of string into database so usually we will store the string directly into the database by either using a prepared statement or a batch statement. Now I want to insert list of string into a database, so I have used a prepared statement.

```java
    List<String> Account_Number = Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt"))

    .filter(s -> s.contains(arra.get(7)))
    .map(s -> s.split(":")[1].trim())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(Account_Number);

     try {
            Connection conn = PDFTOEXCEL.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into client_info values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    stmt.setString(1, Account_Number);
int k = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I have about 31 columns in my database. Just for showing I have posted only one in this code. All are in the list of the string only.

Comment: Assuming the list represents the values of those 31 columns in order what prevents you from looping over it and calling `stmt.setString(index, value)`? Besides that, you should work on your naming, e.g. `Accout_Number` would indicate a single value rather than a list (or more specificly in the Java world it would look more like a mix of a class name because of it starting with a upper case letter and a constant because of the underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the parameters one by one? Something like this:

```
        int size = Account_Number.size();
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            stmt.setString(i, Account_Number.get(i-1));
        }
```

Comment: So basically every question mark in the SQL statement represents a parameter, in your case, it's 30 parameters/columns. 
And  `stmt.setString(i, Account_Number.get(i-1));` will set the the value for the parameter/column  at index Y.
So Here I'm assuming the `Account_Number.size()` does match the number of columns in your table

Comment: k can you show how to put that statement into my program still i am not getting what actually u are saying if you don't mind

Comment: Account_Number is my one of the Column in my database table i have created table under Client_info this is my table name

Comment: Can you post the `client_info` table definition?  i.e the name and index of all columns. 
So if  `Account_Number` is the first column in your table, you need to set `stmt.setString(1, Account_Number.get(1));` and then for the other 30 columns `stmt.setString(COLUMN_INDEX, "Column Value");` 

Bear in mind that `Account_Number` is a list of String, probably a list of account numbers.

Comment: I am getting an error while (query_set.next()) {
                row_counter = row_counter + 1;   Account_Number = query_set.getString("Account_Number");  error:incompatible types: String cannot be converted to List<String>     /* data into the Map */